# Difference between different kinds and brands of reeds on the alto sax

Tags: saxophone, reeds

I've been playing with traditional Vandoren reed strenght 3, and Rico Royal strengt 3,5

I want to try the Vandoren Java.

What is the difference between red and green java? And is is a big difference from the traditonal Vandoren or Rico?

Comment: This is entirely a matter of what works for you.  Not to mention that, if reeds are anything like what they were in my playing days :-( , you'll have to try at least a couple boxes' worth to decide if the good ones are to your liking.

Comment: True that what you prefer is a matter of what works for you, but I think the questioner is asking about the objective difference between two products by the same manufacturer. Since I haven't actually used them, I'll just post this as a comment, but according to their website the red box is supposed to be more flexible and have more "tonal body" than the green. My guess is that green will be a bit firmer and easier to control, but red may have more pitch flexibility.

Comment: As a clarinetist, I find that Vandorens are about 1/4 strength harder than Ricos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a local music shop, I'd suggest going down there and sampling a few different varieties. I, personally, have found little success with the JAVA series and have seen better consistency in Rico Jazz Select (cheaper, too!).